# How to use deal with custom database types in CakePHP ORM? Persist and Fetch Spacial data

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0

Ill try to tell the long story short:

MySQL has a spatial `Point` data type for some time. To insert data we need to use expression of `INSERT (...) VALUES (POINT(lon lat) ...)`. To do that in CakeORM we need to have our given property as `new QueryExpression("POINT($lon,$lat)");` and the CakePHP will handle data binding upon saving entity.

Now what I want to do is to *Have entity with property (field) of type GeoJSON Point that corresponds to Mysql column of type `Point` as well and the ability to store and fetch entities to and from the db*

I have used `beforeSave` call back for that in such manner:

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event, \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, ArrayObject $options) {
    $coords = $entity->position->getCoordinates();
    $entity->position = new \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression('POINT(' . $coords[0] . ',' . $coords[1] . ')');
}
```

where `$entity->position` is of Type `Point`(additional lib, but this could be anything). This works in general, but modifies actuall entity so if i do

```
$entity->position=new Point(5,10);
$table->save($position);
$entity->position // <- this will be Query expression insteed of Point(5,10);
```

And in the third step I want to still have my `Point` object, and not modified value -`QueryExpression`.

I know that CakePHP supposed to have support for custom database datatypes but it is useless due to... well it just does not work as I would expect it to work. Here is a GitHub issue describing why remomended (by the docs) solution does not work.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8041